# Connect to remote host from windows using SSH/pem

Tags: ssh, putty, telnet, chmod

So I have a .pem and I need to connect to a remote machine using that.

I have been told to do: `ssh -i key.pem root@remote machine`

Before that I am supposed to `chmod 600/400 on key.pem`

I am on windows. When I type `ssh` or `chmod` it says unrecognized command..
How can I connect to this remote host?

Comment: Believe it or not, you already answered your question when you tagged your question with `putty`. Read up on it and read our [help] to learn why this question is not appropriate here.

Comment: @SvW I am a non-believer...

Answer (score 4):

You can load your .pem key into putty and save it as .ppk file to access the server.

PEM format if you are going to connect from Linux, OS X or other Unix systems and PPK for Windows Putty, FileZilla and WinSCP.

For reference :

http://cloudarch.co.uk/2011/09/create-ppk-file-from-pem-using-putty-to-connect-to-ec2/#.U80E5ZUvAhc

Comment: Reason for downvote please

Comment: Not sure who downvoted your answer.. +1ed by me, thanks for your answer! I was lost at the pem file thingy, but your link really helped